# How to count number of times a condition is met across a row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['steve', 'josh', 'mike'],
                   'one': [0.4, 0.8, 0.2],
                   'two': [1, 0.1, 0.1],
                   'three': [1, 1, 0.99]})
```

that looks like this

```
name   one   two  three  
steve  0.4   1    1
josh   0.8   0.1  1
mike   0.2   0.1  0.99
```

I would like to add a new column to this table that counts how many times a specific condition is met across each row. If a value is **not equal to 1**, then count it.

The result should look like this

```
name   one   two  three  sums
steve  0.4   1    1      1
josh   0.8   0.1  1      2
mike   0.2   0.1  0.99   3
```

I'm really unsure how to approach this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My translation of "If a value is not equal to 1, then count it" (using `select_dtypes` to consider only numeric columns):

```
df['sums'] = df.select_dtypes('number').ne(1).sum(axis=1)

print(df)

    name  one  two  three  sums
0  steve  0.4  1.0   1.00     1
1   josh  0.8  0.1   1.00     2
2   mike  0.2  0.1   0.99     3
```

Comment: This answer seems about as direct as you can get... why the thumbs down?

Comment: (not my DV, but there seems to be a lot of downvoting in pandas questions recently, perhaps linked to questions showing no effort / research, and perhaps by extension, answers to these questions)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.ne` (not equal) and sum along rows using the argument `axis=1`:

```
df['sums'] = df[['one','two','three']].ne(1).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: I think he wants `.ne(1)`

Comment: Except, of course, that he really wants the count that are NOT equal to 1.

Comment: yeah my mistake! fixed it

Comment: Thanks for editing my question so that it makes more sense and thank you all for helping with this. I wouldn't have gotten this on my own.